# APEX 5, change value of select list by button e text

Tags: button, selectlist, oracle-apex-5

I just start using apex from few time. So I hope you'll forgive me if I ask things that are very simple.
I have a select list populated by a SQL Query, my SQL instruction is `SELECT NUM, ID FROM TABLE`.
I'd like to change the query dynamically adding a " `WHERE NUM LIKE %myVar%`", where "`MyVar`" is the test of a text Item, so I'd like to change the content of the select list pressing the button.
Is it possible?
thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find a partial solution. I bind to select list a PL/SQL function returning a SQL Script and I add an text item called *filter*.
My function is:

```
declare 
  q varchar2(4000);
begin 
  q:='select numero, ';
  q:=q||'id from t_doc ';
  q:=q||'where numero = :FILTROPT';
  return q;
end;
```

But if I use like with a percent in the function instead of "=", apex raise me an error.
Any suggestion?